# Reading in file into a string array

Tags: java

How do I read in a file into a string array using Scanner? The file has a specified number of lines, lets say 100. There are plenty of examples in here using `arrayList` and `BufferedReader` but not Scanner or arrays that are already fixed in size.

```
public String[] array;
Scanner inputStream = null;     
public String line;

public practice(String theFile) {      
    array = new String[100];
    try {         
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(theFile)); 

        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

                //dont know what to put here         
             }
         }           
     } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
     inputStream.close();   
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check for has next line because you have a fixed length and a try catch to handle it all. Just use the for loop but not the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check for has next line because you have a fixed length and a try catch to handle it all. Just use the for loop but not the while loop. From there, it's just all scanner stuff:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = inputStream.nextLine();        
}
```

Comment: I see, once I took of my while loop it worked. Thank you very much! Once I reach 15 rep points I make sure to upvote your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;

while (inputStream.hasNextLine() && i < array.length())
{
    array[i] = inputStream.nextLine(); 
    i++;
}
```

Comment: not a problem :)  **i must say:** using a try..catch block as a pettern of not handling common exceptions (such as out of range) is a very bad practice. please use try.. catch ONLY when the effort of trying to map all the posibble exceptions and their solutions is not possible or the resulted code will probably will be too messy

Comment: Hm, but the reason I used a try and catch was because I kept getting compile errors which were due to exceptions.